# Location services permission alert disappears

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I am asking for *requestWhenInUseAuthorization from CLLocationManager* and the user prompt displays but then quickly disappears.

According to other posts on *SO* it says that you have to declare your CLLocationManager var at the class level to fix this.
Problem is that I am already doing this and this still happens.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
class myLocation: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var locationManager:CLLocationManager?
    // Have also tried it as: let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    func start() {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()

            guard let manager = self.locationManager else {
                print("Error creating Location Manager")
                return
            }

            manager.delegate = self
            manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
        else {
            print("Location Services Disabled")
        }
    }

    //Delegate Methods
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        switch status {
            case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
                manager.startUpdatingLocation()

            default:
                manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: How are you creating your instance of `myLocation` (And it it should be called `MyLocation`)?; it is probably being released, which means your location manager will be released.

Comment: I show 2 ways that I have created the instance above. The name of the var doesn't matter, you can call your vars anything. I agree that its probably being released, the problem is I am doing what you should do to keep a reference (putting the var at the class level)

Comment: Not the name of the var, the name of the class. By convention classes in Swift start with a capital. It will still work with a lower case letter, obviously, but using a capital helps you (and others) know that you are referrimg to a class and not a variable.  You haven't shown where you are creating the instance of the `myLocation` class. You have shown how you are creating the location manager, but the location manager is a property of `myLocation` so if that class is being instantiated as a local variable in a function then it will be released as soon as the function exits

Answer (score 1):

The key to fixing this was that the var I instantiated this class too was a local var. I moved that to a class var and it no longer disappears.

So for example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let location = myLocation.init()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        location.start()
    }
}
```